# How to acknowledge existing digital ocean droplet with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I have a droplet (virtual machine) running on Digital Ocean, which has been created from another laptop. Machine is called "production". I do have that token which been used to create that machine. And I'm really puzzled in here, how to "acknowledge" that droplet on another computer. I don't want to recreate it, as in one of containers I have database which has some data. Controlling DO droplets with docker-machine/compose seems to be quite comfortable. The only problem, sometimes I need to switch laptops in here. Also as sometimes Digital ocean droplet just disappears in a vain from `docker-machine ls`, but it's running on DO.

Vagrant actually had this kind of feature with digital ocean plugin, it's possible to acknowledge already running VM in there. I'm pretty sure this must be possible with docker-machine too.

Comment: There is an open issue about this: https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/1328

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the only way `docker-machine` "saves state" is through the configuration files it creates. Each host spun up with `docker-machine` creates a folder holding its configuration under `~/.docker/machine/machines/` Information about the DigitalOcean Droplet is stored in a `config.json` file. Let's look at a specific one as an example:

```
$ cat ~/.docker/machine/machines/docker-001/config.json | jq .
{
  "DriverName": "digitalocean",
  "Driver": {
    "AccessToken": "9dasd89ssf6542notarealtoken455b44sdgf4685",
    "DropletID": 4906043,
    "DropletName": "",
    "Image": "ubuntu-14-04-x64",
    "MachineName": "docker-001",
    "IPAddress": "45.32.128.70",
    "Region": "nyc3",
    "SSHKeyID": 7697371,
    "Size": "512mb",
    "CaCertPath": "/home/asb/.docker/machine/certs/ca.pem",
    "PrivateKeyPath": "/home/asb/.docker/machine/certs/ca-key.pem",
    "DriverKeyPath": "",
    "SwarmMaster": false,
    "SwarmHost": "tcp://0.0.0.0:3376",
    "SwarmDiscovery": ""
  },
  "CaCertPath": "/home/asb/.docker/machine/certs/ca.pem",
  "ServerCertPath": "",
  "ServerKeyPath": "",
  "PrivateKeyPath": "/home/asb/.docker/machine/certs/ca-key.pem",
  "ClientCertPath": "",
  "SwarmMaster": false,
  "SwarmHost": "tcp://0.0.0.0:3376",
  "SwarmDiscovery": ""
}
```

So syncing the `~/.docker/machine/` directory between your computers should do the trick.

Comment: Nice information, would be nice to specify that SSHKeyID, so then with generic driver id be able to plug this machine back.